# How to show Alert on Apple Watch

Tags: objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

How to show Alert on apple watch. Is  there any alternate to show alerts in the Apple Watch because I checked and UIAlertView is not working on Apple Watch.

Comment: Updated my answer. With watchOS2 I believe you have a better solution for what you wanted :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**With watchOS2**

With watchOS2 you can use the [WKAlertAction](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKAlertAction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKAlertAction/actionWithTitle:style:handler:) method:

```
+ (instancetype nonnull)actionWithTitle:(NSString * nonnull)title
                                 style:(WKAlertActionStyle)style
                               handler:(WKAlertActionHandler nonnull)handler
```

**With watchOS1**

If you don't mind losing the feature of an UIAlertView of seeing the content behind, you can:

1 - Create an ErrorInterfaceController (with or without an ok button)

[image]

2 - Set the identifier to "ErrorInterfaceController"

[image]

3 - Present that error with:

```
[self presentControllerWithName:@"ErrorInterfaceController" 
                        context:@{@"title" : @"yourTitle",
                                  @"text"  : @"yourText"}];
```

4 - In your ErrorInterfaceController.m you can set your title and text with the context.

Note that your ErrorInterfaceController can have a title that is empty and the ok button can dismiss it or you can leave the way it is with a default "Done".

This is the simplest solution to present a message.

If you want something more complex you need to remember that WatchKit doesn't have a z-index and you can't add elements dynamically by code. Therefore, you need to have a solution that uses UIImages rendered in your app extension and sending them to the WatchKit.

Comment: plz explain in deep.where to put code ? what to do in controller to pass context?

Comment: Completed the answer with some images. The ideia is basically define a new interface controller that is responsible to present an error and then simply present it.

Answer (score 11):

**Update for Swift 3.0 - In watchOS 3.0**

```
let action = WKAlertAction(title: "Decline", style: WKAlertActionStyle.default) {
        print("Ok")
    }
    presentAlert(withTitle: "Message", message: "Please select value. Swipe right to change it.", preferredStyle: WKAlertControllerStyle.alert, actions:[action])
```

Hope it helps !!!

Answer (score 7):

For watchOS 2, here is an example:

```
WKAlertAction *action =
            [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                     style:WKAlertActionStyleDefault

                                   handler:^{
                                       // do something after OK is clicked
                                   }];

NSString *title = @"Oops!";
NSString *message = @"Here comes the error message";

[self.interfaceController
            presentAlertControllerWithTitle:title
                                    message:message
                             preferredStyle:WKAlertControllerStyleAlert
                                    actions:@[ action ]];
```

Answer (score 5):

**In watchOS 2**

***Objective-C***

```
NSString *titleOfAlert = @"Something Happened Wrong";
NSString *messageOfAlert = @"Error Message Here";
[self.interfaceController presentAlertControllerWithTitle: titleOfAlert
                                                  message: messageOfAlert
                                           preferredStyle:
                                            WKAlertControllerStyleAlert
                                           actions:@[
                                              [WKAlertAction actionWithTitle: @"OK"
                                                             style: WKAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                             handler: ^{
                                                                //something after clicking OK
                                                             }
                                           ]];
```

***Swift***

```
let titleOfAlert = "Something Happened Wrong"
let messageOfAlert = "Error Message Here"
self.interfaceController.presentAlertControllerWithTitle(titleOfAlert, message: messageOfAlert, preferredStyle: .Alert, actions: [WKAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default){
    //something after clicking OK
}])
```

**In watchOS 1**

You should make a second interface controller, as Tiago says, then present the second one from the first one:

***Objective-C***

```
[self presentControllerWithName:@"ErrorInterfaceController" 
                    context:@{@"title" : @"yourTitle",
                              @"text"  : @"yourText"}];
```

***Swift***

```
self.presentController(name: "ErrorInterfaceController", context:["title":"yourTitle" , "text":"yourText"])
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to put your alert UI in a group and show/hide it as necessary. Depending on your app's design this can work quite well. I do something similar for showing loading UI.